# Dispose() causes dreaded Visual Studio "Unable to copy file from obj to bin' error?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

After searching many solutions I just found out that the overridden Dispose method of a Control causes the dreaded VS bug "Cannot copy file from obj/ to bin/ ..." (in my case)

If this Dispose method is included, VS will throw the error each time you make code changes and try to rebuild. If the overridden dispose method is commented out, problems disappear ...

What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Visual Studio feature?

```
public class StyledLabel : Control
{
    private ImageList imageList;

    public ImageList ImageList
    {
        get { return imageList; }
        set { imageList = value; }
    }

    public StyledLabel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }        

    // This method causes dreaded VS Error ??
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (imageList != null)
            {
                imageList.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**Edit: unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error anymore, so I'm even more lost now ... The vs error message went away though...**

Comment: which version of visual studio? I tried the above program with VS2010 and it worked just fine.

Comment: vs2008 ... unfortunately i can't reproduce the error anymore either ...

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the ImageList before disposing.

Comment: Thanks, did that, but because i cannot reproduce the error anymore i can't check if that was the cause of the problem ...